# Move table <tfoot> to the right with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have this table that I can't edit its `<tfoot>` HTML tag, it's rendered with a PHP function that can't change. So I can't change the `<tr>` inside the `<tfoot>`.

How can I move the red area (x1, x2) to the right with just CSS?

https://jsfiddle.net/qL03728p/

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

table td {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

thead {
  background: green;
}

tbody {
  background: yellow;
}

tfoot {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>thead 1</th>
      <th>thead 2</th>
      <th>thead 3</th>
      <th>thead 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>tbody 1</td>
      <td>tbody 2</td>
      <th>tbody 3</th>
      <th>tbody 4</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>x1</td>
      <td>x2</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

Comment: Be aware that visual alignment without structural alignment leaves your table with poor accessibility. Those using assistive technology (screen readers, etc.) will have a tough time deciphering your data. Dropping in two empty table cells with PHP or JavaScript is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another answer mentions, this seems quite difficult to achieve without the use of JavaScript, particularly as the `td` elements are missing from the `tfoot`.

However, there is an alternative solution using a transformation that uses `translateX` on the `tfoot`:

```
tfoot {
    background: red;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

This moves the whole element by 50% to the right.

As pointed out by @isherwood in the comments, this has the unhelpful side-effect of creating a horizontal overflow on the table.  This can simple be corrected by setting `overflow: hidden` on the table CSS:

```
table {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here it is in a working snippet:

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    overflow: hidden;
}
table td {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
thead {background: green;}
tbody {background: yellow;}
tfoot {
    background: red;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
    
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>thead 1</th>
            <th>thead 2</th>
            <th>thead 3</th>
            <th>thead 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>tbody 1</td>
            <td>tbody 2</td>
            <th>tbody 3</th>
            <th>tbody 4</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    
     <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>x1</td>
            <td>x2</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    
</table>
```

Comment: And one caveat: This solution assumes uniform column widths. As tables are fluid, as soon as one column has wider content, things will get goofy. Set fixed column widths to prevent problems.

Answer (score 0):

Without using Javascript, it's do-able but not in the clean way. (Or not that I know of)

I don't think you can modify the HTML structure with only CSS but you could do something like this:

```css
tfoot {
  position:relative;
  background: red;
  left:20%;
  }
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5xm74nw/)**

You can play with the "left" attribute's value to get it exactly how you would need.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    overflow:hidden;
}
table td {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
thead {background: green;}
tbody {background: yellow;}
tfoot {
  position:relative;
  background: red;
  left:25%;
  }
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
    
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>thead 1</th>
            <th>thead 2</th>
            <th>thead 3</th>
            <th>thead 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>tbody 1</td>
            <td>tbody 2</td>
            <th>tbody 3</th>
            <th>tbody 4</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    
     <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>x1</td>
            <td>x2</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    
</table>
```

---

If you had the possibility to use Javascript, you could add a "" tag to the structure, right before the "x1"  tag. Give it a class name so that you can customize it with css. That would nudge the other two to the left properly.